# Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have developed one web application in 32 bit using asp.net (visual studio 2008). Target CPU was "x86". Now I am converting it into 64 bit. I made Target CPU as "x64". I have converted all required DLLs into 64 bit. But now it is giving error for 64 bit DLL as "Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." If I remove reference of the 64 bit DLL which causes this error then it gives error for another 64 bit DLL. I also tried with Platform property values as "x64", "Any CPU", "All platforms". But did not work. Please help me.

Comment: Are you experiencing the error when you are trying to run an ASP.NET application on VS development server?